# send UIImage as bytes?

Tags: iphone, sockets

I have a UIImageView which contains a image taken with the camera of the phone.

Next thing that i want to do is send this image to a server. I already have the socket connections set up using the CFstreams.

But i really can't get this to work. I have a UIImage object, which i want to send over somehow with my TCP connection...

I tried to send a NSData like so, but it gives me an error:
Code:

```
// Getting image from OpenCV and converting it back to UIImage
NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageWithCVMat:tpl]);
uint32_t length = (uint32_t)htonl([data length]); 

// Send the image? (Doesn't work)   
[outputStream write:[data bytes] maxLength:length];
```

> error: Semantic Issue: Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'const
>   uint8_t *' (aka 'const unsigned char *') with an rvalue of type 'const
>   void *'

So anyone any idea how to send an image from a UIImage(View) as a byte array through the outputStream writer??

Comment: why would you do htonl on something that you don't send over the wire?

Comment: @unbeli I just found that snippet somewhere, you can ignore that line :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you can safely cast:

```
[outputStream write:(const uint8_t *)[data bytes] maxLength:length];
```

since you know where the (void*) data comes from.