# Unexpected error when getting bitmap data from UIImage?

Tags: ios, objective-c, bitmap, uiimage, core-graphics

I am getting the following error. and couldn't find anything related on google search.

Zero results..

I mean.. seriously , thats really weird.

**ERROR :-**

```
Cannot initialize a variable of type 'UInt8 *' (aka 'unsigned char *') with an rvalue of type 'void * _Nullable'
```

**MY CODE :-**

```
UIImage *image = self.image;
CGImageRef originalImage = [image CGImage];
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef bitmapContext  =
CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL,CGImageGetWidth(originalImage),CGImageGetHeight(originalImage),
                      8,CGImageGetWidth(originalImage)*4,colorSpace,kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
CGContextDrawImage(bitmapContext, CGRectMake(0, 0,
                                             CGBitmapContextGetWidth(bitmapContext),CGBitmapContextGetHeight(bitmapContext)),
                   originalImage);
UInt8 *data = CGBitmapContextGetData(bitmapContext);
```

**SCREEN SHOT :-**

[image]

**PS:-**

I am using this code in  .mm file, if it helps.

Comment: [this might help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169420/send-uiimage-as-bytes)

Answer (score 0):

```
+ (unsigned char ) convertUIImageToBitmapRGBA8:(UIImage ) image {

    CGImageRef imageRef = image.CGImage;

    // Create a bitmap context to draw the uiimage into
    CGContextRef context = [self newBitmapRGBA8ContextFromImage:imageRef];

    if(!context) {
        return NULL;
    }

    size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
    size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);

    // Draw image into the context to get the raw image data
    CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, imageRef);

    // Get a pointer to the data    
    unsigned char bitmapData = (unsigned char )CGBitmapContextGetData(context);

    // Copy the data and release the memory (return memory allocated with new)
    size_t bytesPerRow = CGBitmapContextGetBytesPerRow(context);
    size_t bufferLength = bytesPerRow * height;

    unsigned char *newBitmap = NULL;

    if(bitmapData) {
        newBitmap = (unsigned char )malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)  bytesPerRow * height);

        if(newBitmap) { // Copy the data
            for(int i = 0; i < bufferLength; ++i) {
                newBitmap[i] = bitmapData[i];
            }
        }

        free(bitmapData);

    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error getting bitmap pixel data\n");
    }

    CGContextRelease(context);

    return newBitmap;   
}

+ (CGContextRef) newBitmapRGBA8ContextFromImage:(CGImageRef) image {
    CGContextRef context = NULL;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;
    uint32_t *bitmapData;

    size_t bitsPerPixel = 32;
    size_t bitsPerComponent = 8;
    size_t bytesPerPixel = bitsPerPixel / bitsPerComponent;

    size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(image);
    size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(image);

    size_t bytesPerRow = width * bytesPerPixel;
    size_t bufferLength = bytesPerRow * height;

    colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    if(!colorSpace) {
        NSLog(@"Error allocating color space RGB\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    // Allocate memory for image data
    bitmapData = (uint32_t *)malloc(bufferLength);

    if(!bitmapData) {
        NSLog(@"Error allocating memory for bitmap\n");
        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
        return NULL;
    }

    //Create bitmap context

    context = CGBitmapContextCreate(bitmapData, 
            width, 
            height, 
            bitsPerComponent, 
            bytesPerRow, 
            colorSpace, 
            kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);    // RGBA
    if(!context) {
        free(bitmapData);
        NSLog(@"Bitmap context not created");
    }

    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    return context; 
}

+ (UIImage ) convertBitmapRGBA8ToUIImage:(unsigned char ) buffer 
        withWidth:(int) width
       withHeight:(int) height {


    size_t bufferLength = width  height  4;
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, buffer, bufferLength, NULL);
    size_t bitsPerComponent = 8;
    size_t bitsPerPixel = 32;
    size_t bytesPerRow = 4 * width;

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    if(colorSpaceRef == NULL) {
        NSLog(@"Error allocating color space");
        CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
        return nil;
    }

    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast;
    CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;

    CGImageRef iref = CGImageCreate(width, 
                height, 
                bitsPerComponent, 
                bitsPerPixel, 
                bytesPerRow, 
                colorSpaceRef, 
                bitmapInfo, 
                provider,   // data provider
                NULL,       // decode
                YES,            // should interpolate
                renderingIntent);

    uint32_t* pixels = (uint32_t*)malloc(bufferLength);

    if(pixels == NULL) {
        NSLog(@"Error: Memory not allocated for bitmap");
        CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);
        CGImageRelease(iref);       
        return nil;
    }

    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixels, 
                 width, 
                 height, 
                 bitsPerComponent, 
                 bytesPerRow, 
                 colorSpaceRef, 
                 bitmapInfo); 

    if(context == NULL) {
        NSLog(@"Error context not created");
        free(pixels);
    }

    UIImage *image = nil;
    if(context) {

        CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, width, height), iref);

        CGImageRef imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

        // Support both iPad 3.2 and iPhone 4 Retina displays with the correct scale
        if([UIImage respondsToSelector:@selector(imageWithCGImage:scale:orientation:)]) {
            float scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
            image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:scale orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
        } else {
            image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
        }

        CGImageRelease(imageRef);   
        CGContextRelease(context);  
    }

    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);
    CGImageRelease(iref);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);

    if(pixels) {
        free(pixels);
    }   
    return image;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

//Swift-3

**CGBitmapContextGetData(bitmapContext)** has been replaced by **CGContext.data**

let data = context.data

[image]